# Sorting Arrays descending with integers

Tags: arrays

I am working on an assignment and need guidance. Below is an array for a Patient class that I am trying to get to sort by pntID number; that the user inputs in a textbox. Im sure the issue somewhere in the sort method. Thank You

```
 Patient[] patients = new Patient[6]
            {new Patient(pntName1.Text,pntID1),
            new Patient(pntName2.Text,pntID2),
            new Patient(pntName3.Text,pntID3),
            new Patient (pntName4.Text,pntID4),
            new Patient (pntName5.Text,pntID5)};
                Array.Sort(patients);
            int[] sortedCopy = patients.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: patients.OrderBy(patient => patient.pntID).ToArray(); ?